# Combine (merge) 2 arrays by keys and change keys name in the result array

Tags: php, arrays

I have these two arrays as output:

```
Value Array
(
    [0] => 10100153
    [1] => 2007
    [2] => 350
    [3] => 804082
    [4] => WW006
    [5] => WHT/NNY/OXGM
    [6] => 35/38
    [7] => 804082         WW00635/38
    [8] => 0,00138857
    [9] => Champion 3pk Quarter Socks
)
Numbers Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
    [9] => 10 
)
```

I want to combine them and change the key value of the value array in value and the numbers array in numbers, so it looks something like this:

**Desire output**

```
['Value' => '10100153', 'Number' => 1],
['Value' => '2007', 'Number' => 2],
['Value' => '390', 'Number' => 3],
['Value' => '804715', 'Number' => 4],
['Value' => 'WW001', 'Number' => 5],
['Value' => 'WHT/WHT/WHT', 'Number' => 6],
['Value' => '39/42', 'Number' => 7],
['Value' => '804715         WW00139/42', 'Number' => 8],
['Value' => '0.00138857', 'Number' => 9],
['Value' => '3pk Quarter Socks', 'Number' => 10]
```

All I can find is `array_combine` and `array_merge`, but `array_merge` just adds the numbers array to the end of the value array, and `array_combine` adds the numbers to the end of the text of the value array

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: a simple for loop should suffice, at least have a go at it

Comment: You should be able to use array_map or just a for loop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `array_map` ([doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)) and `array_combine` ([doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)) as:

```
$res = array_map(null, $valuesArray, $numbersArray);
$keys = array("Value", "Number");
$res = array_map(function ($e) use ($keys) {return array_combine($keys, $e);}, $res);
```

**Notice** the use of `null` in `array_map`. From documentation:

> An interesting use of this function is to construct an array of arrays, which can be easily performed by using NULL as the name of the callback function

This way you can merge more arrays - just remember to add the correct key to `$keys`

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/YCbe7)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop to iterate over your values array. At each element in the values array you can get its corresponding element in the numbers array by using the current index.

At each iteration (each loop of your values array) you can add an associative array into a resulting array (here I called it `$res`).

See example below:

```
$values = ["10100153", "2007", "350", "804082", "WW006", "WHT/NNY/OXGM", "35/38", "804082       WW00635/38", "0,00138857", "Champion 3pk Quarter Socks"];
$nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

$res = []; // create empty array to hold associative arrays
foreach($values as $i=>$val) { // loop over your values array, where the index is $i and the value is $val
    $num = $nums[$i]; // get the number at the given index
    $res[$i] = ["Value" => $val, "Number" => $num]; // set the index in the resulting array to hold a newly formed associative array 
}
print_r($res); // print the results
```

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the extra round of iterating (while transposing with `array_map(null...)`) as demonstrated in dWinder's answer by passing both input arrays into `array_map()` and using the splat operator to receive the arguments inside the function.  My snippet will have half of the computational complexity of dWinder's solution -- just one loop instead of two.

From PHP7.4 ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/k7XDA))

```
$keys = ["Value", "Number"];
var_export(
    array_map(fn(...$data) => array_combine($keys, $data), $values, $numbers)
);
```

Before PHP7.4: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/4KuCT)) ([or with compact()](https://3v4l.org/SeJ44))

```
$values = ["10100153", "2007", "350", "804082", "WW006", "WHT/NNY/OXGM", "35/38", "804082 WW00635/38", "0,00138857", "Champion 3pk Quarter Socks"];
$numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

$keys = ["Value", "Number"];
var_export(
    array_map(function(...$data) use ($keys) {
        return array_combine($keys, $data);
    }, $values, $numbers)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'Value' => '10100153',
    'Number' => 1,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'Value' => '2007',
    'Number' => 2,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'Value' => '350',
    'Number' => 3,
  ),
  ...you get the point
)
```