# How to Loop through multi dimensional array of $_FILES array

Tags: php, arrays

I am using dropzone to get the files uploaded to my Folder. Successfully getting the array of files.

```
   foreach($_FILES as $file) {
       print_r($file);
    }
```

**Current Output:**

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Image.PNG
            [1] => sadssadsa.PNG
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => image/png
            [1] => image/png
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => C:\Users\CH MANAN\AppData\Local\Temp\php48B6.tmp
            [1] => C:\Users\CH MANAN\AppData\Local\Temp\php48B7.tmp
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 291647
            [1] => 112790
        )
)
```

**Expected output**:

```
array
(
    [0] => array
    (
        [name] => Image.PNG
        [type] => image/png
        [tmp_name] => C:\Users\CH MANAN\AppData\Local\Temp\php48B6.tmp
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 291647
    )

    [1] => array
    (
        [name] => sadssadsa.PNG
        [type] => image/png
        [tmp_name] => C:\Users\CH MANAN\AppData\Local\Temp\php48B7.tmp
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 112790
    )
)
```

Tried various loops in the parent loop but not getting the expected results. Someone can help here.

Comment: So what's the problem with rebuilding array? And btw this is __standard__ `$_FILES` for multiple files uploaded.

Comment: @u_mulder I don't know how to build that array. Thats the problem. I have tried various loops inside but not getting the expected output.An example might help.

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54902354/6487675

Comment: Is the loop with print_r outputting your current output?

Comment: @Andreas yes thats with print_r

Comment: So you only have one array in $_Files? Can you at least look at my answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$keys = array_keys($_FILES); // get all the fields name
$res = array_map(null, ...array_values($_FILES)); // group the array by each file
$res = array_map(function ($e) use ($keys) {return array_combine($keys, $e);}, $res); // insert the field name to result array
```

Documentation:

[array-keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), [array-map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [array-combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/2FdGC)

Comment: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements

Comment: getting `array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["type"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["tmp_name"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["error"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["size"]=>
  bool(false)
}`

Comment: What output you get for `$res = array_map(null, ...$_FILES);`? (maybe I miss the $_FILES structure)

Comment: `array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) "sadssadsa.PNG"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "SLIP.PNG"
  }
  ["type"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "image/png"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "image/png"
  }
  ["tmp_name"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(47) "C:\Users\CH MANAN\AppData\Local\Temp\php5BC.tmp"
    [1]=>
    string(47) "C:\Users\CH MANAN\AppData\Local\Temp\php5CC.tmp"
  }
  ["error"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(0)
    [1]=>
    int(0)
  }
  ["size"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(112790)
    [1]=>
    int(112968)
  }
}
`

Comment: @MR_AMDEV Problem was with missing `array_values` - updated

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: Why `...` before array_values ?

Comment: This php operator who break array of array to separate arrays - because array map takes array and not array of arrays

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example:

```
$source = [
    'name' => [
        'test1',
        'test2'
    ],
    'type' => [
        'jpg',
        'png'
    ]
];
$result = [];

foreach ($source as $key => $subArray) {
    foreach ($subArray as $index => $value) {
        if (!array_key_exists($index, $result)) {
            $result[$index] = [];
        }
        $result[$index][$key] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

it first looks at the (file) index. if the index does not exist in  `$result` it will be added. And than it adds the key with value to the corresponding index.

you should work on the basics (manipulating multidimensional arrays et cetera) before advancing. do you have a tutorial or sth else you follow and learn from?

Answer (score 1):

You can loop the array and use array_combine and array_column to transform the array.

```
foreach($_FILES as $file) {
    $keys = array_keys($file);
    foreach($file['name'] as $key => $f){
        $new[] = array_combine($keys, array_column($file, $key));
    }
}
var_dump($new);
```

See working example:
https://3v4l.org/6lL8J

Comment: As you can see my expected output requires one array and Keys should have value not arrays.

Comment: @MR_AMDEV **THEY ARE EXACTLY THE SAME!** Look at this then, now I use print_r. Does it look better? https://3v4l.org/cOlUk

Comment: @MR_AMDEV and opposed to the accepted answer mine does not create notices and warnings. https://3v4l.org/qWONV

Comment: Thanks for that .Just overlooked to the code and realized that its the output.

Answer (score 0):

The output for `$_FILES` that you see is a **standard** output for multiple files uploaded. You can iterate over one subarray of `$_FILES` (for example `name`) and get values from other subarrays under the same key:

```
foreach ($_FILES['name'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value, $_FILES['error'][$key], $_FILES['tmp_name'][$key];   // etc
}
```